# adding new element and attribute for xml in c# using linq

Tags: c#-4.0

This is my XML file i want to add new "proj" element and a attribute to that bases on the condition ,that project name   is already there or not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<projects>
  <proj name="project1">
    <file_type Type="internalmeeting">"path1"</file_type>
  </proj>
  <proj name="project2">
    <file_type Type="externalmeeting">"path2"</file_type>
  </proj>

</projects>
```

i m able to add the element but it adding each time i click "save" button.

Comment: Well have you looked at any of the XML APIs available in C#? I'd suggest that you read up on LINQ to XML. Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Comment: yes jon i did that ,actually my problem is to check the condition.

Comment: Check what condition? You've said about "the condition" but not explained what condition you're talking about. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: sorry for inconvenient question.i have a textbox in a form when user enters the project name code should check existing nodes and should decide to add or not to add.

Comment: Okay, so does the answer you've received satisfy that? (It looks fine to me.)

Comment: yes thats work perfect

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the project exists with the given name like this before you add a new element:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
if(!doc.Descendants("proj").Any(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == projectName))
{
    // add new project
}
```